# deployment-specific resources in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple e-commerce web application. When I made the application, I thought that it would be deployed as a single website, so the `.cshtml` files look like this:

```
<head>
    <title>My Company Storefront</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to My Company online store" />
    ....
</head>
```

Now the web application will be deployed as a second website. Some of the content needs to change:

```
<head>
    <title>Second Company Storefront</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Second Company online store" />
    ....
</head>
```

The two deployments will share the same code, but some of the text content in the `.cshtml` files will be different.

What is a good method to achieve this?

I have seen the `.resx` system, but it seems a little heavy. Each deployment would have only one resource file. Also, I expect external programmers/admins to make changes to the resources.

Is `.resx` suitable?

Comment: If you are trying to make a separate presence (for a different business) I recommend either going the CMS route and making it database driven, or creating separate projects entirely.  Otherwise, you're probably going to end up with a lot of `if (company == "company X") then...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this. You have explored the `resx` options (that would work). That content could also be pulled from a database of some sort. Since you are using asp.net, why not look at the `Web.config` and transforms option.

In your baseline Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Description" value="Welcome to My Company online store"/>
</appSettings>
```

If you have a project configuration of `SecondCompany` (as well as the usual debug and release), you can have a `Web.SecondCompany.config` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Description" value="Welcome to Second Company online store"
         xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Upon deployment, you can configure your Web.config to be transformed based on the deployed configuration. Deployment of the `SecondCompany` configuration will result in:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Description" value="Welcome to Second Company online store"/>
</appSettings>
```

Which can be modified directly without deployment as the Web.config is a simple XML file.

In your view, you can replace the content part with:

```
<head>
    <title>My Company Storefront</title>
    <meta name="description" 
          content="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Description"]" />
    ....
</head>
```

More information on Web.config transformation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd465318(v=vs.100)).

Comment: Wow. People actually use transforms?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: You've apparently never had to work on a project that wears multiple hats, or needed to vary connection string based on what you're working on (local debug vs remote deploy). ;p

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yep. It's a useful tool. If you have a Test environment, a Lab environment, etc.. configuration transformation on connection strings and settings is a very good way to change the settings based on the deployment. It's not the end of all things, though.

Comment: @BradChristie Of course I have.. at multiple companies. Not a single one has used web config transforms for any of their applications!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will use the `.config` route, though I will put the brand data in a different `.config` file with its own section, to improve readability. I don't want to load down `appSettings` too much.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could do worse than have a database at the back-end (which you probably already have if this is an Online Store), in which you could keep a table of translations which could then be modified on a per-site basis.

```
_id     _expression    _translation
-----------------------------------
1       msgtitle        Welcome to My Company online store
```

Which could of course be modified in the 2nd website.

To use translations, load them in to a dictionary of some sort during application initialisation, and use the expression as the key and the translation as the value:

```
<head>
    <title>Second Company Storefront</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@MyCache.Translate["msgtitle"]" />

</head>
```

Comment: Though make sure to cache these entries since they're very rarely going to change per request and the last thing you need is an additional DB call for every page visit.

Comment: @BradChristie, yup!  That's why I suggested loading them in to a dictionary during application initialisation :)